# Add watermark and audio using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, watermark

I need to add a watermark (logo) and audio to my videos. I am currently using the below 2 commands:

```
ffmpeg -i 27650.mp4 -i TTS-Audio-Music.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -c:v copy -c:a copy Z:\02Videos\Final\27650.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i 27650.mp4 -i IGR-Video-Service-75%.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" Z:\02Videos\Final\27650.mp4
```

But I am able to use only 1 of the above 2 properly, every time I use the 2nd command after using the 1st one,

I get an error like this one:

[image: Obnoxious screen shot]

I have even tried using the watermark command first and then adding the audio, but still getting an error.

I tried to merge both the commands using the **","** but keep getting errors as I am making some mistake which I am unable to figure out.

Please help me with a way to add both the audio and the watermark to my videos, and I would love it if I can do it with a single command.

The files I am using can be downloaded here - https://we.tl/t-0Njnj2yLy0

Comment: Please let me know if my suggested solution works. I don't have your input files, so I can't be sure... (note: you forgot to post the code that gives the error message).

Comment: Please don't provide screen shots of error messages. We need to be able to copy/paste the text of the error message, just like we need to be able to copy your code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have added the files I am using and can be downloaded here - https://we.tl/t-0Njnj2yLy0

Comment: This is the error I am getting to Rotem's suggested command - Stream map '1:a:1' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use temporary name for the output of the `overlay` filter, and map it:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 27650.mp4 -i TTS-Audio-Music.mp4 -i IGR-Video-Service-75%.png -filter_complex "[0][2]overlay=10:10:format=yuv444[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv444p -c:a copy Z:\02Videos\Final\27650.mp4
```

---

- `"[0][2]overlay=10:10:format=yuv444[v]"` overlay the (video) from the first input with the third input (the PNG image).
  The overlay output gets the temporary name `[v]`.
  (`format=yuv444` is optional - used for improving overlay quality).
- `-map "[v]"` maps `[v]` to the output video stream.
- `-map 1:a` maps the audio stream of the second input (`TTS-Audio-Music.mp4`) as output audio stream.
- `-c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv444p` selects output video codec and encoding parameters.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I got this error now - https://snipboard.io/AYns8J.jpg

Comment: The files I am using can be downloaded here - https://we.tl/t-0Njnj2yLy0

Comment: This is the error I am getting - 
Stream map '1:a:1' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.

Comment: Replace `1:a:1 with 1:a`. I thought you are trying to map the second audio stream, but it looks like you have only one audio stream.

Comment: You may also avoid the mapping: `ffmpeg -y -an -i 27650.mp4 -vn -i TTS-Audio-Music.mp4 -i IGR-Video-Service-75%.png -filter_complex "[0][2]overlay=10:10:format=yuv444" -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv444p -c:a copy test.mp4`

Comment: I tried both the commands you have suggested (with and without the mapping), in both cases I am getting a file of 20.4 MB, but it does not play, just gets stuck on 0.00 seconds with the loading circle infinitely rotating. I tried multiple video players, same issue, and none show any error.

Comment: Please download my files and check at your end, as it might help you understand why we are getting this errored output.

Comment: Try `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. In my machine my origanl command is working. What video player are you using? Try new version of VLC Player. Update the codecs - install K-Lite if you are using MPC-HC.

Comment: It worked, had to make it "format=yuv420" too. Thank you very much for all your help, it is highly appreciated.